# stop resetting select input whenever new select option is added when button is click

Tags: javascript, html

I successfully create new select if the button is click. but how do i stop the selected being refresh whenever I add another select?

it's kind hard for me to explain but here's the code:

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="here" colspan="2"> </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" ><a style="color: #4F7942; cursor: pointer;" onclick="add()">Add Select</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
function add(){
var container = document.querySelector(".here");

if(container){
    container.innerHTML += `
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="abc" name="any[]">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select....</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    `;
}
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/idfrnffnd/akjpLc2y/4/

Comment: Do not add content with innerHTML

Comment: @epascarello okay... then how should i do it?

Comment: appendChild and createElement

Comment: Or `insertAdjacentHTML()`

Comment: There's nothing *always* wrong with adding content, but in this case your code completely rebuilds the contents of that element, so *all* the `<select>` elements are recreated.

Comment: Seems very odd you are adding an entire table to insert a new row into a table cell. Why are you not adding the row to an existing table?

Comment: @epascarello back in the day, adding a  single row to a `<table>` in IE required one to add a new `<tbody>` to the `<table>`, with that new row inside. I don't know whether that's still the case, but the old IE engine had a really bizarre architecture for tables.

Comment: @epascarello that's just an example of mine. the real one is kinda long and have other elements inside the table separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not alter `innerHTMl`, instead, use [`container.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
function add(){
    var container = document.querySelector(".here");
    
    if(container){
        container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
                <select class="abc" name="any[]">
                  <option value="" selected disabled>Select....</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                  <option>3</option>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        `);
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td class="here" colspan="2"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" ><a style="color: #4F7942; cursor: pointer;" onclick="add()">Add Select</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```